# How to parse this JSON to extract the orderinfo JsonArray

Tags: java

I am having the following JSON shown below

```
{
    "vendors": {
        "T1": [
            {
                "name": "Inorbit_Vendor 02",
                "data": {
                    "tax_details": {
                        "contact_phone_no": "9866545439"
                    },
                    "orderinfo": [
                        {
                            "contact_phone_no": "9866545439"
                        },
                        {
                            "contact_phone_no": "9866545439"
                        },
                        {
                            "contact_phone_no": "9866545439"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Inorbit_Vendor 01",
                "data": {
                    "tax_details": {
                        "contact_phone_no": "9866545438"
                    },
                    "orderinfo": [
                        {
                            "contact_phone_no": "9866545438"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to read the orderinfo array ??

i have tried as following

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;


String ordersplitjson = ""; // Above JSON 


        try
        {
            JSONObject jsonOrder = new JSONObject(ordersplitjson);
            JSONArray jsonT1Array = jsonOrder.getJSONObject("vendors").getJSONArray("T1");
            System.out.println(jsonT1Array.length()); // length is 2 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Could anybody please help me how to read this orderinfo JSONArray ??

Comment: does [this](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/11/json-to-hashmap-parsing-json-string.html) help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily iterate over json Array:

```
 JSONArray jsonT1Array = jsonOrder.getJSONObject("vendors").getJSONArray("T1");
 for(int i = 0; i < jsonT1Array.length(); i++) {
    // Get the objects in T1 array
    JSONObject objectInArray = jsonT1Array.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("data"); 

    // Then get the JSONArray you want
    JSONArray jsonOrderArray = objectInArray.getJSONArray("orderinfo");

    // You may iterate again over ordeinfo array
    for(int j = 0; j < jsonOrderArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject objectInOrderArray = jsonOrderArray.getJSONObject(j);
        String orderNumber = objectInOrderArray.getString("contact_phone_no");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject jsonOrder = new JSONObject(ordersplitjson);
JSONArray jsonT1Array = jsonOrder.getJSONObject("vendors").getJSONArray("T1");
for(int i = 0; i < jsonT1Array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonT1ArrayObject = jsonT1Array.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject jsonData = jsonT1ArrayObject.getJSONObject("data"); // data
    JSONArray jsonOrderInfo = jsonData.getJSONArray("orderinfo"); // orderinfo

    // iterating order info
    for(int j = 0; j < jsonOrderInfo.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject foobar = jsonOrderInfo.getJSONObject(j);
        String contactNo = foobar.getString("contact_phone_no");
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer you've accepted was wrong and someone downvoted it. Later he fixed it and probably by seeing my anwswer. anyway welcome :)